# Node.JS webapp: Authentication, Create Account, Forgot Password and Change Password

Tags: node.js, authentication, registration, change-password, forgot-password

I would like to develop a new web-app in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (using [express](https://expressjs.com/)). I am relatively new to node.js world, so I assume there are frameworks that I am not familiar with.

Is there any framework (like [Spring](https://spring.io/) for Java) that manages authentication (and save the trouble from the developer)? Or each developer has to write this code over and over again?

Login/Logout is not all. There are other flows:

- registration (create account),
- forgot-password (and then set new password),
- locking/unlocking an account,
- change password

and I think I have covered all flows.

I know that each application has its own UI, forms, maybe with its logo, but the **flow itself is similar** for most applications.
In addition, I know that it is not that hard to implement, but it could be great to have some kind of tool / framework / infrastructure which implements the flows.

Is there such a tool/framework which helps applications' developers and implements these flows?

I've searched this issue but could not find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago I have developed [authentication-flows](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows) for Java over Spring, and recently I wrote [authentication-flows-js](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows-js).

It is a module that answers most flows - authentication, registration, forgot-password, change password etc., and it is secured enough so applications can use it without the fear that it will be easily hacked.

It is **for node.js applications** (written in TypeScript) that use express. It is an **open source** (in GitHub). A release version is on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/authentication-flows-js), so you can use it as a dependency in your `package.json`.

In its README (and of course in the npm page) there are detailed explanations for everything and if something is missing - please let me know. An article will be published soon (I will add a link as a comment).

You can find [here an example for a hosting application](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows-js-app).

> NOTE: I have heard comments like "It's not so difficult to implement". True.
> But you have to make sure you take care of all cases. For example,
> what happens if a user tries to create account that is already exists?
> what happens if a user tries to create account that is already exists
> but inactive? what about the policy of the password? (too long/too
> short/how many capital etc.) what about sending the email with the
> activation link to the user? how you create this link? should you
> encrypt it? what about the controller that will receive the click on
> the link and activate the account? and more...

Comment: The article: https://ohad-redlich.medium.com/authentication-create-account-forgot-password-and-change-password-for-node-js-ae1df4df9b43